# Обновление SSL Let's Encrypt - Wild Card сертификата после получение его через DNS acme-challenge

Tags: linux, ssl, wildcards

Нужно было получить сертификат для ***.domain.com**

```
certbot certonly -d *.domain.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns
```

Ввёл емайл ... - получил.

Всё работает.

Проблема только в том, как его **автоматически обновить** ?

Так как эмитация обновления с помощью команды:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Пишет мне что для ***.domain.com** нужно опять подверждать что-то по DNS.

Где логика ? Я думал одного подвреждения достаточно - так как при обновлении они автоматически проверяют запись в DNS.

Или им всё время нужна новая запись с новым ключом ? Я что-то не пойму.

Главный вопрос - как это сделать ?

Comment: Через время владелец домена может внезапно (или не внезапно) измениться, поэтому вполне логично, что каждый раз нужно подтверждать, что у вас по-прежнему есть контроль над доменом. А чтобы подтверждать автоматически, нужно выкинуть опцию `--manual` и подключить плагин для интеграции с тем DNS-сервером, который управляет вашим доменом

Comment: «они автоматически проверяют запись в DNS» — при каждой проверке создаётся новая TXT-запись, а после успешной проверки запись удаляется

Comment: Не слышал о таком. Можно пример такого хостера?

Comment: Его уже нет - по этому - теперь приходится разбираться со всем несущим. По поводу реализации, есть какие-то примеры ?